# WPF binding StringFormat syntax

Tags: wpf, binding, string-formatting

How can I format a decimal value conditionally in a WPF window?

1. Value should be rounded to a whole number (Ex: 1,234)
2. When the value is 0.00, it should display as a single zero. (Ex: 0)

Currently I use bellow mark up to format the decimal value, but it displays 00 when the value is 0.00. Please help.

```
<TextBlock
  Grid.Column="6"
  Padding="2"
  Text="{Binding Path=TotalAwardsExpended, StringFormat='{}{0:0,0}'}" />
```

Answer (score 52):

The extra 0 comes from the 0 after the colon.

Instead, try `{}{0:#,0}`.

From the [MSDN docs on Custom Numeric String formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) (emphasis added):

> "0" | Zero placeholder | Replaces the zero with the corresponding digit if one is present; **otherwise, zero appears in the result string**.