# Concatenate literals and staticresource string purely in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

i tried this:

```
Sets literally Show {Binding Source={StaticResource AppInfoer}, Path=Title}
<MenuItem Header="Show {Binding Source={StaticResource AppInfoer}, Path=Title}" 
Command="{StaticResource ShowWindowCommand}" CommandParameter="Open" />
```

given `Header="{Binding Source={StaticResource AppInfoer}, Path=Title}"` resolves nicely to "Main App", how could I successfully

- prepend the literal string "Show "
- to the string output from `{Binding Source={StaticResource AppInfoer}, Path=Title}`

im hoping for a no additional code-behind solution, one that involves **just an xaml line or two**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using [StringFormat](http://elegantcode.com/2009/04/07/wpf-stringformat-in-xaml-with-the-stringformat-attribute/)?

```
{Binding Source={StaticResource AppInfoer}, Path=Title, StringFormat=Show {0}}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it shows just "Main App" when i copied your code inside the MenuItem Header? i.e. it does not prepend the "Show "..

Comment: Maybe `MenuItem` or `Header` does not support `StringFormat`? Also no luck [with `{}`](http://elegantcode.com/2009/04/07/wpf-stringformat-in-xaml-with-the-stringformat-attribute/) and [single straight quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167833/wpf-binding-stringformat-syntax).

Comment: In the end, got it to work with alternative implementation `internal class PrependConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return string.Format("Show {0}", value);
        } //... }` and in XAML `<tn:PrependConverter x:Key="PrependConverter"/>` plus `<MenuItem Header="{Binding Source={StaticResource AppInfoer}, Path=Title, Converter={StaticResource PrependConverter}}">`