# String format in wpf

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, textbox, string-formatting

I have a `TextBox` on `WPF` that is related to the float variable in my model

Following the TextxBox:

```
 <TextBox Text="{Binding Position, StringFormat=f4}"/>
```

I want that TextBox will display a maximum 4 numbers after the point.

So I put `StringFormat=f4`.

But now, even when I have less than 4 numbers after the point and when I have a whole number it displays with 4 digits after the point.

**For example, the number 0 is shows that: 0.0000**

I want as long as it did not pass the four numbers, display it in a normal way, how can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could try with `StringFormat="{}{0:0.####}"`

This syntax with `{}` is due to the fact that we set a WPF property equal to a string that contains curly bracket symbols. Curly bracket symbols are interpreted by WPF in a particular way and would not be interpreted as part of the string. Without the `{}` the code would not compile. `{}` allows you to set a WPF to a string value that contains curly bracket symbols.

You can have for example a look at the link [String formatting in WPF and Silverlight](http://web.archive.org/web/20130907220845/http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2010/08/31/c-string-formating/)

Comment: Can you explain what the meaning of the line?

Comment: But why i see only 3 numbers ?

Comment: Actually if Position is 0.12345, you should see 0.1235. At least on my PC this is what happens

Comment: Right!! Me too he is doing. But when I put this number: 1234.36456465445 is introduced: 1234.365

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this link about [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx). I think this is what you might be looking for.

Or alternatively, try this;

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Position, StringFormat='{}{0:#,0000}'}"/>
```

Hope this helps! :)

EDIT:

This previous question might help also;

[WPF binding StringFormat syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167833/wpf-binding-stringformat-syntax)