# Need help developing and Binding a Double <--> Converter

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, wpf-controls

I develop engineering applications and therefore constantly deal with `double` numbers. Being a newbie and since ComboBoxes and other controls prefer strings, my models are string-based:

```
Diameter = "0.523";
```

I have done Google searches and have some preliminary (confusing, contradictory) info about Converters: could use a unified explanation.

The `IValueConverter` interface establishes a `Convert()` and a `ConvertBack()` pair, but which is the direction of each? The Converter is XAML bound to, say, a `TextBox` and my model deals with `double`. Does the `Convert()` half act going **out** of the `TextBox` or into it?

My objective is to add a warning near the red rectangle that is formed when illegitimate numbers are typed: "The floating point number that you typed has an incorrect format".

I wrote 2 Convertor classes: `DoubleToString` and `StringToDouble`. Not sure which is the proper one (plus, both are crashing).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of the time people only use the Convert method for their work. 
ConvertBack is used in when convertion is need for both side. XAML to Model vice versa

Here is a sample for double. You can further format the value as per your need.

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(double) ,typeof(string))]
public class DoubleConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value ,Type targetType ,object parameter ,CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double doubleType = (double)value;
        return doubleType.ToString();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value ,Type targetType ,object parameter ,CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string strValue = value as string;
        double resultDouble;
        if ( double.TryParse(strValue ,out resultDouble) )
        {
            return resultDouble;
        }
        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup, you are definitely missing something: patience, plus the fact that people and machines are NOT the same.

Answer (score 0):

Convert is used to convert your model's value to the textbox. ConvertBack converts the textbox's value back to your model.

Your said you kept strings in your models. This means you don't need a convertor at all. However, you'd better put doubles in your models and convert them properly.

Also, if you only need one way conversion (from your model to the control), you don't need a converter at all. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16439402/string-format-in-wpf) for example.

Comment: "See here for example." That 'here' is missing.  :-) Was there supposed to be a link?

Comment: Oops, sorry. Fixed now.