# WPF Alternative of converter in WPF which is testable

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, mvvm, converters

I have my cutomer view which contain listbox containing Customer list.
In list box I would like to show (Firstname + Lastname)(Attributes of Customer) but don't want to use converter for each customer in list.
Model customer class is being somewhere so that can't be changed.

Any Idea how can I do that?

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Answer (score 1):

If your model object is "somewhere that can't be changed" then you are out of luck.

A converter is very testable, it is simply a class that implements IValueConverter or IMultiValueConverter, all your test class has to do is call the `Convert()` method and test the return value.

Alternatively if you can skip testing you can use [string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167833/wpf-binding-stringformat-syntax) [formatting](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2008/05/29/trying-out-binding-stringformat.aspx) [in your binding](http://elegantcode.com/2009/04/07/wpf-stringformat-in-xaml-with-the-stringformat-attribute/) of your list item template.

Comment: Yes, I understand converter are testable but was looking for any other option available which is testable as well.

Comment: @ManojKawatra There isn't another realistic option.