# Show binded values in WPF without parsing

Tags: wpf, data-binding, string-formatting

I bind single properties to a TextBox without a specific StringFormat with the intension to show the value exactly like the user entered it.

```
<TextBox x:Name="TBSingleValue" Text="{Binding Path=SingleValue, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
```

The current automatic StringFormat creates the following result:

123456789   =>  1.234568E+08
0.123456789 =>  0.1234568

I need to display the values within -10e-9 and 10e9 without the scientific formating or automatic round.

With a StringFormat:

```
<TextBox x:Name="TBSingleValue" Text="{Binding Path=SingleValue, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, StringFormat={}{0:F9}}" />
```

it parsed as expected but now I get every Decimal place, even when the value doesn't need one.
4 => 4.000000000

So here my Question:
Do you know what kind of StringFormat I should use to display every enteres Decimal place without showing unnessessary ones?
Best case would also a support of , and . as Decimal delimiter.

**Edit:**

I came up with a quite simple solution:

```
<TextBox x:Name="TBSingleValue" Text="{Binding Path=SingleValue, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, StringFormat={}{0:0.###########}}" />
```

The custom StringFormat character # shows a digit only if one is present. The 0 at the beginning ensures that there is a 0 at the beginning even for numbers of 0.001.
This structure disables the scientific notation and gives the number with the required precision, without unnecessary 0 at the end.

Even -0.00000001 is displayed correct.

Comment: "show the value exactly like the user entered it" - use `string` property as binding source, not numeric

Comment: Well, that would be an ugly soulition, because I have to parse and verify it manually in the background.  This would also eliminate the benefits of automatic parsing when binding to a numeric property.

Comment: there are many examples here, for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167833/wpf-binding-stringformat-syntax
you can always use a converter to do whatever you need if you can't find a format that fit

Comment: That is not an ugly solution, but a valid solution for an ugly requirement like "show the value **exactly** like the user enetered it"

Comment: Why is it an ugly requirement? I need the single value to be displayed without unnessessary decimal digits and with up to 9 possible ones.
But think that I will create a Costom Control and parse everything like needed. 
I post it here when its done, so others can profit.

Comment: Hi. The part "exactly like the user entered it" is problematic if you don't want to go deeper in parsing what the user entered via code behind (converter or Text property). What about 1.0000000000000000000009 ? A double isn't enough, you need a decimal, and the # reaches its limit at some point. What if the user entered a scientific value ? Anyway, you selected an outcome that suits your needs, now is your question still a relevant one on StackOverflow ?

Comment: Hi, you mentioned an interessting Point. That was the reason why I choose the automatic parsing through binding to a float property. Even an input as scientific value would be parsed.  My Question wasn't clear enough, which resulted in some missunderstanding.  Maybe someone can learn from it and my solution.